# Downloading images in the background in flutter

Tags: flutter

Hi everyone I need help with downloading images in background in our flutter app

We are showing users list of images in our app we need to allow users to select these images and save them to thier phone but the download has to happen in the background so that the user can continue using rest of the features of the app

Our app is developed in flutter
Our backend is written in laravel 8
And database is SQL

I am a newbie and so I don't have much clarity regarding what more information shud I put in to help you all understand the code so I am adding a screenshot of the UI of our app search page
where we need to allow users to select multiple images and save them to their phone local storage but the download has to happen in background as the image size is big

Answer (score 0):

You can use a async function where you call it and the app goes on. In the background all images are going to be saved on the phone while you still can use the app